# Data structure which offers both insertion/removal from/to both ends and retrieval from middle constant effort?

Tags: java

I was wondering whether is there a data structure that offers constant effort (O(1)) for both insertion/removal from/to both ends, as for example a LinkedList offers, and retrieval from a random index, as for example a HashMap offers.

Or maybe if I can achieve something similar somehow with a combination of data structures.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) fits all your requirements. Quoting its Javadoc:

> Most ArrayDeque operations run in amortized constant time.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Is `arraydeque.remove(object)` constant effort?

Comment: `remove(Object)` is O(n) due to the implied linear search. Element removal (dequeueing) on its own is O(1).

Comment: @assylias      That's what I know too.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik As I describe in my question, I need O(1) for insertion/removal to/from both (or at least one) end(s) as well as O(1) for insertion/removal from/to a random index or for a random object (random = unknown a priori).

Comment: I thought op wanted O(1) for insert/remove from both ends which ArrayDeque provides. The only thing is random access which is O(n). Now that op has clarified the requirement is O(1) for random insert/remove, this answer would not serve that purpose.

Comment: The structure itself supports O(1) random access, but unfortunately it is not exposed through the abstraction. Insertion/removal from the middle is another thing, but your question did not request it.

Answer (score 1):

A [hashmap](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm) is the fastest data structure i think

remove: O(1)
size: O(1)
values: O(n) (on traversal through iterator)

Comment: It seems, as I thought after searching a lot, that there is no perfect solution: either you will have O(1) insertion/removal at end but O(n) retrieval/insertion at the middle or  the other way arround, but at the end you will have, implicitly or explicitly, perform a "search" (for loop) somewhere.